# How to use JQuery Dialog to post sub-set of data on form and refresh parent in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery dialog which is rendered in a partial view within a main view.

I want the form to post the whole parent page back so it is refreshed on submitting the data.  However, the model that I use is stored in a class off the main model class e.g. MainModel.Current

At the top of the dialog I have the link to the MainModel (@model...)
Then in the helpers use lambda like so: m => m.Current.Field

In the controller, the model being passed into the parameter of the function is null?
Is there any reason for this?  How do I go about passing in a different model or a subset of the model and refresh the parent.
Its a nightmare in mvc.

**Updated**

In main view:

```
@model MyProject.ParentModel
...
Html.RenderAction("AddChildData");
```

In partial view:

```
@model MyProject.ParentModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ChildData.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChildData.Name)
```

In controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddItem(ParentModel parentModel)
 {
    myService.AddItem(parentModel.childData); <-- parentModel is null
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

Comment: Having a hard time picturing what you are saying. Can you show how you are rendering the sub view, as well as the controller data?

Comment: Hi,I've added an update. The problem is posting a sub-set of the parent data to the main form that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was because I had a nested form and this was intercepting the model data of the parent form.